# GameKit Framework bugged or outdated?

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center, gamekit

I am currently working on game center implementation on an app. i have followed this tuto [Tutorial 1](http://forum.thegamecreators.com/?m=forum_view&t=191580&b=44) and this [Tutorial 2](http://vivianaranha.com/integrating-apple-gamecenter-to-your-application/) both of them have this GKLocalPlayer line

```
[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer]
```

i followed the steps slowly and surely but everytime i compile my work im having this

**GKLocalPlayer underclared** and **GKScore** and some other in GK.

*i am wondering is there something wrong in my Game Kit Framework?*

i cant seem to find the problem because others who tried those tutorials got it successfully.

here is a part of the code which includes the GKLocalPlayer (in tutorial1):

```
- (void) authenticateLocalUser
{
    if([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == NO)
    {
        [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) 
         {
             [self callDelegateOnMainThread: @selector(processGameCenterAuth:) withArg: NULL error: error];
         }];
    }
}
```

PS: my simulator is ios4.0 my xcode is 3.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GKLocalPlayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) (documentation linked for you) was introduced with iOS 4.1, as was [the rest of the Game Kit functionality](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304).

Target iOS 4.1 and newer, make sure you have the GameKit framework included in your project, and let us know if you have the same problems.

Comment: im still getting the xcode 4.2 i guess this will take some time.. i hope you will still be there after this :)

Comment: well... I'll probably be sleeping soon (since programmers need to get some shut eye, too).  If you have the exact same problem with XCode 4.2 and targeting iOS 4.1 and newer, then buzz me here again; otherwise post any new questions as a new post and no doubt somebody else will be eager to help you out.

Comment: ok thanks i guess ill accept your answer now :) if i still have the same issue ill be posting a new one... thanks again